# Failed to execute 'send' on 'xmlhttprequest' failed to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello guys I'm getting the error mentioned in the headline when i try to a run my app created in DevExtreme.

Whenever Í run my app in the DevExtreme simulator it works as it should but when I try to run the app on my phone I get the mentioned error.

```
    function CallService() {
    var baseAddress = "http://192.168.80.2:8080/WebService/rest/WarehouseServices/";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: baseAddress + 'getPickingOrders',
        contentType: 'applicaiton/xml; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "xml",
        async: false,
        success: function (xmlObject) {
            xml = xmlObject;
            console.log("succes ramt");
            alert(xml);
            console.log(xml);
            dataSource = GetData(xmlObject);
        },
        error: ErrorOccur
    });

}
```

I have been strugling with this problem for a long time now and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: *`async: false`* Why? *Why?* It makes for a horrible UX.

Comment: We could use more context. Where is this code running? The other SO questions I see with this specific error message talk about the code being part of a Chrome extension -- is that the case here?

Comment: The code is running in a framework called DevExtreme which also able to simulate the code as it would be a a mobile phone. 

I'm not sure what you mean about being a party of a Chrome extension. The app is only giving this error when running on my phone and not in the simulator

Comment: Re `async: false`: Sure it will, you just need to use the callback correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure how that works, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Look at just about any example of using `ajax`. The key thing is to use the result from within the `success` callback, not to do it in code following the `ajax` call.

Comment: I was facing the same error when making a GET request. Found out that I am sending a huge payload. Changed method from GET to POST. (The api server is also controlled by us. So could change method in backend). Problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page where this script is running isn't on `http://192.168.80.2:8080` and your server doesn't enable [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) for whatever origin it's on, you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prohibits cross-origin ajax.

Comment: The server is accepting cross origin requests. I got the my API running on another machine I will try to run the API and the app on the same machine and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem was solved by adding corresponding headers to the server.