# NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load, wcf-mssql-L4 swicth

Tags: javascript, c#, database, wcf

It seems to timeout after 4 minutes after connecting to the db in wcf and running it.
Not sure, but I'm guessing it's an L4 switch issue.
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This error usually comes up in the context of front and back interaction. What do you do through interaction?

Comment: @Jiayao Select and insert millions of data.
In wcf, data is controlled through mssql and returned to javascript to show on the screen.

Comment: You can take a look at this link : [Failed to execute 'send' on 'xmlhttprequest' failed to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420749/failed-to-execute-send-on-xmlhttprequest-failed-to-load)